# Клиент не видит схему бд H2 на сервере

Tags: java, база-данных, клиент-сервер, h2

Здравствуйте. Возникла проблема - клиент H2 приложения не видит схему на сервере. Ошибка:

> Schema "MY_SERVERDB" not found; SQL statement:
>   SELECT userid, username FROM my_serverdb.MYUSERS

Соль в том, что я с клиента логинюсь пользователем, созданным с сервера. И если указать неправильный пароль, сервер не пускает. Разве пользователи бд не хранятся в этой же бд?

Код сервера:

```
private String path = "jdbc:h2:./h2databases/my_serverdb";
private String settings = ";CIPHER=AES;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;MULTI_THREADED=1";
private String user = "serveradmin";
private String password = "filepassword adminpassword";

public H2Server() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println(":: H2 server side ::");
    // starting the TCP Server
    Server server=null;
    Connection connection=null;
    Statement statement=null;
    ResultSet resultSet=null;
    String sql=null;

    try {
        server = Server.createTcpServer("-tcpAllowOthers", "-webAllowOthers", 
            "-pgAllowOthers").start();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(path+settings, user, password);
        statement=connection.createStatement();

        System.out.println("Port: "+server.getPort());
        System.out.println("URL: "+server.getURL());
        System.out.println("Status: "+server.getStatus());

        sql =   "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MYUSERS("+
                "userid int, username varchar(255),"+
                "PRIMARY KEY(userid) )";
        statement.execute(sql);
        sql = "INSERT INTO MYUSERS (userid,username) VALUES (1,'denis')";
        statement.execute(sql);
        sql = "INSERT INTO MYUSERS (userid,username) VALUES (2,'fil')";
        statement.execute(sql);
        System.out.println(connection.getCatalog());

        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT userid, username FROM MYUSERS");
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            String userid = resultSet.getString("userid");
            String username = resultSet.getString("username");
            System.out.println(userid+" "+username);
        }

        /*
        DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();
        ResultSet rs = meta.getTables("./serverdata", null,"%", null);
        System.out.println("tables list:");
        while (rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
        }*/

        // makes new user
        sql = "CREATE USER MARY PASSWORD 'Marypassword'";
        statement.execute(sql);
        // gives mary rights only to read
        sql = "GRANT SELECT ON MYUSERS TO MARY";
        // sql = "GRANT ALTER ANY SCHEMA TO MARY";
        System.out.println(
            statement.execute(sql)
            );
        server.start();
```

Код клиента:

```
private String path = "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/h2databases/my_serverdb";
private String user = "MARY";
private String password = "Marypassword";
public H2Client() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    System.out.println(":: H2 client side ::");

    Connection connection=null;
    Statement statement=null;
    ResultSet resultSet=null;
    String sql=null;

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(path, user, password);
        statement=connection.createStatement();
        System.out.println(connection.getCatalog());
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT userid, username FROM my_serverdb.MYUSERS");
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            String userid = resultSet.getString("userid");
            String username = resultSet.getString("username");
            System.out.println(userid+" "+username);
        }
```

(вырезал лишние куски, которые не нужны для проблемы)

Comment: Если изменить название схемы на PUBLIC, то он начинает ругаться на таблицу:
Table "MYUSERS" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT userid, username FROM PUBLIC.MYUSERS [42102-196]

Comment: Если я правильно помню, то при работе с H2DB не нужно указывать схему, то есть запрос должен быть: SELECT userid, username FROM MYUSERS.
Пробовали?

Comment: Теперь "Таблица "MYUSERS" не найдена", в принципе, с этого я и начинал. Потом дописал название схемы, т.к. тогда таблица называлась просто USERS и я подумал, что это имя может быть зарезервировано

Comment: Ещё, server.start() не принимает на вход Connection, а startWebServer принимает и открывает браузер с гуи. Но так тоже не находит, вроде. И ещё System.out.println(statement.execute("GRANT SELECT ON MYUSERS TO MARY")); пишет в консоль false. С чем это связано?

Comment: Воспроизвел ваш код, скажите, у вас кусок     sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MYUSERS("
                    + "userid int, username varchar(255),"
                    + "PRIMARY KEY(userid) )";
            statement.execute(sql);
            sql = "INSERT INTO MYUSERS (userid,username) VALUES (1,'denis')";
            statement.execute(sql);
            sql = "INSERT INTO MYUSERS (userid,username) VALUES (2,'fil')";
            statement.execute(sql);
            System.out.println(connection.getCatalog()); выполняется? Сервер должен стартовать в отдельном потоке.

Comment: Да, кусок выполняется, я потом проверяю это через SELECT. Браузерный гуи тоже всё то, что навставлял, видит. Нужно сервер в Thread оформить? upd; перенос кода в run() у Thread не помогло, клиент всё так же таблицу не видит.

Comment: Думаю проблема в строке подключения клиента. Сервер создает БД в папке проекта, а строка подключения создает БД в папке пользователя, они смотрят на разные БД, вот клиент и не видит таблицу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось гораздо банальнее:
1. Используйте одну строку подключения: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/h2databases/my_serverdb
2. Разберитесь с настройками:  private String settings = ";CIPHER=AES;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;MULTI_THREADED=1"; и аргументами сервера, так как убрав их все заработало.
3. Я надеюсь, что в рабочем коде вы закрываете подключения.

Пару советов:
4. У Вас немного нарушена логика:
- Запуск сервера - это запуск сервера и создание таблиц ни как не связано с ним
- Вынесите создание таблиц и пользователей отдельно
- Не делайте запуск и работу с сервером в конструкторе

Итоговый код, который у меня заработал, хоть и вырвиглаз ))
Сервер:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.h2.tools.Server;

/**
 *
 * @author ezhov_da
 */
public class H2DbTest
{
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(H2DbTest.class.getName());

    private String path = "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/h2databases/my_serverdb";
    private String settings = ";CIPHER=AES;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;MULTI_THREADED=1";
    private String user = "serveradmin";
    private String password = "filepassword adminpassword";

    private Server server;

    private CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public H2DbTest()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {

                try
                {
                    System.out.println(":: H2 server side ::");
                    // starting the TCP Server

                    server = Server
                            .createTcpServer(/*
                             * "-tcpAllowOthers",
                             * "-webAllowOthers",
                             * "-pgAllowOthers" */).start();

                    countDownLatch.countDown();
                } catch (SQLException ex)
                {
                    Logger.getLogger(H2DbTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

        };

        thread.start();

        try
        {
            countDownLatch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(H2DbTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        String sql = null;

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(path/* + settings */, user, password);)
        {

            statement = connection.createStatement();

            System.out.println("Port: " + server.getPort());
            System.out.println("URL: " + server.getURL());
            System.out.println("Status: " + server.getStatus());

            sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MYUSERS("
                    + "userid int, username varchar(255),"
                    + "PRIMARY KEY(userid) )";
            statement.execute(sql);
            sql = "INSERT INTO MYUSERS (userid,username) VALUES (1,'denis')";
            statement.execute(sql);
            sql = "INSERT INTO MYUSERS (userid,username) VALUES (2,'fil')";
            statement.execute(sql);
            System.out.println(connection.getCatalog());

            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT userid, username FROM MYUSERS");
            while (resultSet.next())
            {
                String userid = resultSet.getString("userid");
                String username = resultSet.getString("username");
                System.out.println(userid + " " + username);
            }

            /*
             * DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();
             * ResultSet rs = meta.getTables("./serverdata", null,"%", null);
             * System.out.println("tables list:");
             * while (rs.next())
             * {
             * System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
             * } */
            // makes new user
            sql = "CREATE USER MARY PASSWORD 'Marypassword'";
            statement.execute(sql);
            // gives mary rights only to read
            sql = "GRANT SELECT ON MYUSERS TO MARY";
            // sql = "GRANT ALTER ANY SCHEMA TO MARY";
            System.out.println(
                    statement.execute(sql)
            );
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            LOG.log(Level.ALL, "f", e);
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        while (true)
        {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        H2DbTest h2DbTest = new H2DbTest();
    }

}
```

Клиент:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author ezhov_da
 */
public class Client
{
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName());

    private String path = "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/h2databases/my_serverdb";
    private String user = "MARY";
    private String password = "Marypassword";

    public Client()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        System.out.println(":: H2 client side ::");

        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        String sql = null;

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(path, user, password);)
        {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            System.out.println(connection.getCatalog());
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT userid, username FROM MYUSERS");
            while (resultSet.next())
            {
                String userid = resultSet.getString("userid");
                String username = resultSet.getString("username");
                System.out.println(userid + " " + username);
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            LOG.log(Level.ALL, "f", e);
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Client client = new Client();
    }
}
```

Comment: Как-то неинтуитивно даже. Но вообще теперь это делает смысл. Меня смущало, что Connection никак к Server не присоединялся. И выходит, что юзеры создаются для сервера, а не для бд?

Comment: Так, несколько вещей. Во-первых, в моём коде клиент цеплялся к /~/databases..., а сервер делал /./databases... Точка - каталог, в котором находится приложение. Тильда - домашний каталог пользователя. Как минимум, я неправильно указывал путь. Ну и действительно, если бд без tcp протокола, не выходит вообще к ней подключиться. В принципе, в таком ключе действительно стоит разделить создание бд и сервера. Я же думал, что Connection необходимо передать серверу или вроде того. Но вот такой вопрос - а если бд будет в сети. В начале пути тоже localhost писать, а в клиенте ip сервера?

Comment: Тааак, а теперь я что-то начал понимать. Я перед тем, как создать Connection к бд, делаю server.start(). Это-то и есть запуск сервера, к которому по tcp подключается созданная бд. Вот в этом моменте я и привязываю Connection к Server, по сути.

Comment: Хотя погодите. К шифрованной бд клиенты не цепляются - неверный логинопароль. Неужели её нужно держать расшифрованной всё время работы с сервером? Возможно, я хочу сделать нешифрованную бд, содержащую хеши логинов и паролей, а по ним уже расшифровывать шифрованные бд для конкретных пользователей (если у каждого пользователя своя бд, как в приложении-хранителе паролей). Но, если они работают с одной бд, то получится, что всё время работы её нужно держать расшифрованной?

Comment: @DenisNovac, опишу, как я понимаю данную работу, а так же специфику создания БД в H2DB: 1. Сервер запускается отдельно. 2. В момент первого подключения и "обращения к БД" сервер проверяет ее наличие и создает в случае отсутствия, по-этому при первом обращении нужно устанавливать свойства новой БД, но можно, вроде написано в tutorial-е к H2DB, что можно это переназначить. В итоге, можно выделить несколько этапов создания БД: 1. Запуск сервера 2. Создание и  настройка БД 3. Подключение к БД клиентов. На счет шифрования, не могу сказать, так как не вникал в данный вопрос и не использовал.